# InvalidArgument=Value of '11209485' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index error when running SQL query in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, indexing, database-connection

I keep getting this error "Failure to communicate InvalidArgument=Value of '11209485' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index" when I'm trying to retrieve card numbers from a database and put them in a combo box so that the user can pick their card number in VB.NET 2012. The 11209485 is the first card number in the database, so I assume the connection is fine, but I don't understand this error at all.

I'd be grateful for any help on the matter. Thanks!

Imports MySql.Data

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Dim dbCon As MySqlConnection
Dim strQuery As String = ""
Dim SQLcmd As MySqlCommand
Dim DataReader As MySqlDataReader

' load application Form
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Prepare connection and query
    Try
        dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=***;Uid=***;Pwd=***")

        strQuery = "SELECT CardNumber " &
                   "FROM Account"

        SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

        'Open the connection
        dbCon.Open()

        ' create database reader to read information from database
        DataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader

        ' fill ComboBox with account numbers
        While DataReader.Read
            cboAccountNumbers = cboAccountNumbers.Items(DataReader("CardNumber"))
        End While

        'Close the connection
        DataReader.Close()
        dbCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Failure to communicate" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)


    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
cboAccountNumbers = cboAccountNumbers.Items(DataReader("CardNumber"))
```

You are attempting to read the 11209485th item in the combo box and there aren't that many items.  Try this instead:

```
cboAccountNumbers.Items.Add(DataReader("CardNumber"))
```

Comment: When I change it to that, it underlines it saying: Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'.

Do I need to convert it to an integer?

I know that if I write it as                
cboAccountNumbers.Text = cboAccountNumbers.Text & DataReader.Item("CardNumber") it will output them to the combox box as one string. So do I just need to put a .something after the cboAccountNumbers?

Comment: I got it to work! I changed it to                 cboAccountNumbers.Items.Add(DataReader("CardNumber")) like you said, but left out the "cboAccountNumbers = " at the start! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3275784 - Sorry,  my bad, I meant to remove that.  I will update my post.